# Convert a (LATEX) .tex file into .cls so it can be used in RMarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am interested in getting a [LATEX template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) working in RMarkdown. In the past I have been able to get this to work by implementing a `.cls` document. But this is not available for this template.

In the main directory of the LATEX template I see a `structure.tex` and `main.tex`. Where `structure.tex` seems identical to previous `.cls` files I have used in the past.

Here is an example of how I implemented this in the past within an `.Rmd` document

```
---
title: My Title Goes Here
author: "Author Name"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
documentclass: styles/thesis-umich3 #This is where the .cls document is stored
---
```

This causes me to get the following error claiming that /chaptermark is undefined.

```
`documentclass` searches specifically for a `.sty` file
```

Yet on line 173 I have:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} % Styling for the current chapter in the header
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

Calling a `.tex` document within `in_header` rather than in `documentclass`

```
---
title: "fNIRS Guide"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: style/structure.tex
---
```

This causes the following error

```
tlmgr search --file --global "/numeric.dbx"
tlmgr search --file --global "/biblatex-dm.cfg"
! LaTeX Error: Command \chaptermark undefined.

Error: Failed to compile index.tex. See index.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains numeric.dbx
2: In parse_packages(logfile, quiet = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)) :
  Failed to find a package that contains biblatex-dm.cfg
Execution halted
```

I have also tried to call `documentclass`

```
---
title: "index"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
documentclass: style/structureSavedAsCLS
---
```

This also fails to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on getting this template into a `cls` so I can use it in RMarkdown?

I understand this might be a very entry level question and I was not certain if it was moreso an RMarkdown or Latex question. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the LaTeX command `\input{structure.tex}` early in the main text of your document?  (This assumes it is valid to put it in the body of the document.)  Generally speaking, LaTeX macros pass through Markdown.

Comment: Showing us where and how `structure.tex` is mentioned in `main.tex` would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The particular error `Command \chaptermark undefined.` is caused by `structure.tex` expecting `book.cls`, while rmarkdown uses `article.cls` by default. You could try

```
---
title: "fNIRS Guide"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: style/structure.tex
documentclass: book
---
```

But I expect other incompatibilities between the packages loaded in `structure.tex` and those loaded in the default template. The same type of problems might occur when converting the `tex` to a `cls` file. So instead I would suggest to combine `main.tex` and `structure.tex` to form a new template file. Quoting section [3.3.7.4 Custom templates](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#advanced-customization-1) from the rmarkdown book:

> You can also replace the underlying Pandoc template using the template option:
>
> ```
> ---
> title: "Habits"
> output:
>   pdf_document:
>     template: quarterly-report.tex
> ---
> ```
>
> Consult the documentation on [Pandoc templates](https://pandoc.org/README.html#templates) for additional details on templates. You can also study the [default LaTeX template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex) as an example.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go today.